# Can't login to django with cusom user but for super it work fine

Tags: django, django-authentication

I custom the default user by using AbstractBaseUser and BaseUserManager and also i creat a backend.py which handles authentication Email but it doesn't work, however superuser is work fine

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your custom user admin by providing is_admin = True in your create custom user function.Then only it can login to django.

Comment: I make it dosen't work:                                                                     class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):.....
 
  user.is_admin = True

  return user

Comment: Could you please post the code snippet and more about the error details?

Comment: Thank you very much, it's right when you propose as solution , the problem was in the creation of new custom User, it must be created by the function User.create_user() in the shell not in the admin interface